# Контроль приложений C++

Tags: winapi, книги, c++

Добрый вечер.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью c++ (было бы классно без winapi) контролировать приложения? Не давать исполняться слишком долго, считывать результаты? Если без winapi никак - то как тогда делать это с ним?

Может у кого-нить есть литература\видеокурсы на этот счет?

Comment: Что значит контролировать приложения и считывать результаты?

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Я так понимаю надо прерывать выполнение некоторого наперед заданного процесса при превышении лимита времени и считывать из стандартного потока вывода информацию посылаемую этим процессом(для отображения в окне например). Если так, то я такое делал на С++ с помощью библиотеки Qt, поскольку мне необходимо было кроссплаформенное решение. Если надо могу поделиться исходниками))

Comment: Да, было бы классно :)

Answer (score 1):

Создай второй поток, он будет следить за рабочим потоком.

Comment: не понятно...ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение с применением библиотеки Qt:

```
// qprocesscontroller.h
#pragma once
#include <QProcess>

class QProcessInfo;

class QProcessControllerPrivate;
class QProcessController : 
    public QProcess
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int timeout READ timeout WRITE setTimeout)
public:
    // Конструктор
    explicit QProcessController(QObject* parent = 0);
    // Деструктор
    ~QProcessController();
    // Установить лимит по времени
    void setTimeout(int value);
    // Получить лимит по времени
    int timeout() const;

private:
    // Указатель на внутренние данные (pImpl)
    QProcessControllerPrivate *d_ptr;
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QProcessController)
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QProcessController)
};

// qprocesscontroller.cpp
#include "qprocesscontroller.h"
#include <QTimer>

class QProcessControllerPrivate
{
public:
    QTimer *timer; // таймер
};

QProcessController::QProcessController(QObject* parent /*= 0*/) : 
    QProcess(parent),
    d_ptr(new QProcessControllerPrivate)
{
    Q_D(QProcessController);
    // создаем объект таймера 
    // дочерний для объекта QProcessController, чтобы он
    // удалялся вместе с this
    d->timer = new QTimer(this);
    d->timer->setSingleShot(true); // устанавливаем единственное срабатывание
    // соединяем сигнал запуска процесса со слотом старта таймера
    connect(this, SIGNAL(started()), d->timer, SLOT(start()));
    // соединяем сигнал таймера со слотом принудительного завершения
    connect(d->timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(kill()));
}

QProcessController::~QProcessController()
{
    delete d_ptr;
}

void QProcessController::setTimeout(int value)
{
    Q_D(const QProcessController);
    return d->timer->setInterval(value);
}

int QProcessController::timeout() const
{
    Q_D(const QProcessController);
    return d->timer->interval();
}

// main.cpp - пример использования класса QProcessController
#include <QApplication>
#include "qprocesscontroller.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Создаем объект приложения
    // Это необходимо для запуска цикла сообщений,
    // если этого не сделать, то наше приложение завершится раньше
    // процесса который мы запустим
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

// создаем контроллер процесса
QProcessController ctrl;

// соединяем сигнал завершения процесса со
// слотом завершения текущего процесса
// чтобы прервать цикл обработки сообщений
// и корректно завершить текущий процесс
    // если вы пишите оконное приложение - этого делать не надо
QObject::connect(&ctrl, SIGNAL(finished(int, int)), 
    &app, SLOT(quit()));

// задаем лимит по времени (3 сек)
ctrl.setTimeout(3000);
// стартуем процесс ... 
ctrl.start("calc.exe");

return app.exec();
}
```

Идея решения: класс `QProcessController` - наследник класса `QProcess` и наследует все его возможности (в частности получение данных процесса из stdio, который в примере не освещен, но его легко найти в документации Qt). Сам же класс `QProcess` входит в систему классов Qt и является наследником `QObject`, что позволяет нам использовать систему сигналов и слотов Qt для управления таймером (а через него временем жизни дочернего процесса). Собственно управление происходит следующим образом: при запуске дочернего процесса запускается таймер, как только приходит сигнал от таймера дочернему процессу делается `kill()` (если конечно он не успел закончиться раньше). Можно было бы еще задавать лимиты по используемой памяти и загрузке процессора, но такие решения затрагивают платформенно-зависимые функции ОС... Поэтому в ответе я ограничился этой реализацией. Желаю успехов!

Comment: можно попросить расписать еще подробней, я не понял почти ничего :(

Comment: Что конкретно Вам не понятно? Если Вы не работали с библиотекой Qt, то могу посоветовать посмотреть документацию Qt, которая доступна online, в частности про сигналы и слоты и базовый класс QObject, и посмотреть те классы которые используются в реализации) Успехов!)

Comment: @progzdeveloper, а все-таки какие-то пояснения для не изучавших такую мистическую библиотеку можете написать?

Например,  я вот абсолютно не понимаю, откуда у Вас берется указатель `d` тут

    return d->timer->interval();

или тут

    d->timer = new QTimer(this);

Неужели это как-то связано именно с частью имени `_ptr` в

    QProcessControllerPrivate *d_ptr;

???

Просто очень интересно.

Если это на самом деле так, то вряд ли можно рекомендовать такой продукт (хотя, как я знаю, он широко используется).

Comment: Догадались Вы правильно: я использую так называемую идиому Pointer to Implementation. Дело в том, что такой подход не разрушает бинарнуб совместимость библиотек) Более того такой подход используется во всех классах библиотеки Qt) Вот коллекция ссылок по вопросу: 

http://habrahabr.ru/post/76248/

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer

http://zchydem.enume.net/2010/01/19/qt-howto-private-classes-and-d-pointers/

Comment: Ммдааа...

Что-то мне подсказывает, что программы, использующие такую технологию, размером больше 10000 строк плохо расширяются и пребывают в состоянии хронической отладки.

Comment: Хм.. не понимаю, почему Вы так думаете?